# Differences between Quorum and Pantheon

Tags: quorum, clients, pantheon

I want to build an app on a private blockchain and I'm hesitating between 2 clients : Quorum and Pantheon (now Hyperledger Besu)
Does anyone know what are the main differences between the 2 and the use case for each one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 main differences:

- Besu is a more generic client that support Ethereum mainnet and is written in Java
- Quorum is a fork of geth (go-ethereum, the most used client for ethereum). It does not support mainnet as of now, and as a fork of geth it is written in Go

There are many other differences in terms of ease of setup, ease of use, and various small differences in supported features such as supported consensus algorithms, and enterprise features.

Edit: theres another difference I forgot to mention. While both projects are open-source, Besu is Apache license like all Hyperledger projects, while Quorum inherits LGPL license from geth

Comment: Thank you for your response! Do you have anything in mind when you talk about entreprise features?

Comment: Yeah, theres a ton of difference in those but I think the main thing to note here is that Quorum tooling is open source while Pegasys is planning to separate anything they consider enterprisey and sell it as a package separate from the OS project. Note: this is my understanding as of now.